# Getting resize to work

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to get my resize function to work in my jquery. What I'm trying to do is if my window size is bigger then 769 then it needs to display my hover menu else it shouldn't display it.

My `$(window).load` works but not my `$(window).resize`

Here is my jquery

```
function hover_menu(){
    $('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('> ul').show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find('> ul').hide();
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        var width = $(window).width();

        if(width > 769){
            hover_menu();
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var width = $(window).width();

        if(width > 769){
            hover_menu();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems a bit like the XY problem to me... is this not something you'd usually want to solve with CSS?

Comment: As @nbokmans said, this is easily done with css and [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: but even so shouldn't the resize work though?